# Aurelia with Typescript and async functions: this is undefined

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm using typescript with aurelia and I think I can't find a way to put a variable into the right scope.

```
// detail.ts
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {pApi} from './resources/services/APIService';

let http = new HttpClient();
let httpApi = new pApi(http);

@autoinject
export  class PatDetail {

    newDialog(patId, cat) {
    let burl: string = 'bar/foo/list/';
    const eurl: string = 'foo/bar/list/' + patId + '/';
    let result: string[] = httpApi.getLists(eurl, burl);
    }
}
```

This is the Apiservice-file:

```
// APIService.ts
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

@autoinject
export class pApi {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        http.configure(config => {
            config
                .useStandardConfiguration()
                .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:8000/')
        });
    }

getLists(eurl, burl) {
    async function getQuote() {
        await this.http.fetch(eurl)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }


    async function getBlock() {
        await this.http.fetch(burl)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    async function getBoth() {
        return await Promise.all([getBlock])
    }

    getBoth().then(results => {
        console.log(results)
        return results
    });
}
```

Running this throws the error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: this is undefined

Actually I want to run to independent Promises at the same time and put them into a viewModel. Maybe I could also run it as ordinary Promise-call.
But I thought the rather new async/await call would fit for this solution.

So far I couldn't find any fitting solutions / explanations for my problem. Since I'm new to Typescript and Aurelia I'm stucked.
Thank you for your explanations why this error happens or better approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: rewrote my answer a bit

Donovan is right in his answer that you need to use arrow functions instead of regular functions due to the scoping issue, but I would go a step further and say you probably shouldn't inline them like that.

Async is kind of meant to get rid of the `then` soup. If you're using async, best fully utilize it. You would rewrite your method like this:

```
async getLists(eurl, burl) {
    const results = await Promise.all([
        this.getQuote(eurl),
        this.getBlock(burl)
    ]);

    console.log(results);
    return results;
}


async getQuote(eurl) {
    try {
        const resp = await this.http.fetch(eurl);
        const data = await resp.json();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async getBlock(burl) {
    try {
        const resp = await this.http.fetch(burl);
        const data = await resp.json();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Or to stick to your method, go non-async and simply put the unresolved promises in an array which you can then `.all` at the end:

```
getLists(eurl, burl) {
    const block = this.http
        .fetch(eurl)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    const quote = this.http
        .fetch(burl)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    return Promise.all([block, quote])
        .then(results => {
            console.log(results);
            return results;
        });
}
```

But mixing them = maintenance hell :)

Comment: Great! This works perfectly! My Reputation is too low to upvote your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
async function getQuote() {
    await this.http.fetch(eurl)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Should be this (lose the "function" keyword):

```
async getQuote() {
    await this.http.fetch(eurl)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

With the use of "function" keyword you lose the context to the current object and "this" becomes local within the function alone.

Comment: Sorry, but this throws an error:  Error: src/resources/services/APIService.ts: error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.  unreachable code after return statement

Comment: @Tiehscher I think he missed the fact that the functions were inside of method scope, rather than class scope. So `async function getQuote() {..` should have been `const getQuote = async () => {..` rather than `async getQuote() {..`